# Find date range for every row. LEAD/LAG but with different types/actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following data:

```
Action   Code    Place        Date
Remove   A       Place 1      2019-03-15
Install  A       Place 2      2019-10-01
Remove   A       Place 2      2022-07-12
Install  A       Place 3      2023-01-01
```

There are two actions possible. 'Remove' and 'Install'. How can I find Place for Code A for given date? For example for 2015 it will be Place 1. For 2020 it will be Place 2. For 2025 it will be Place 3.

I think the first and the most difficult step is to transform it to table that contains start and end date. Then I can use between function.

Example output:

```
A   Place   StartDate   EndDate
A   Place 1 1900-01-01  2019-03-15 -- we dont have start date so we can use for ex. 1900
A   Place 2 2019-10-01  2022-07-12
A   Place 3 2023-01-01  3000-01-01 -- we dont have end date so we can use for ex. 3000
```

I have tried with LEAD/LAG but we have two different actions here so I think it is not the best idea. How could I deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why doesn't Place1 start on 2019-03-15 and end on 2019-10-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand.  The following uses `union all` to be sure it gets all values.

```
select code, place, '1900-01-01' as startdate, date as enddate
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by code order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and action = 'Remove'
union all
select code, place, date as startdate, enddate
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 1, '3000-01-01') over (partition by code order by date) as enddate
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'Install';
```

The first subquery handles the case where the data starts with `'Remove'`.  The second takes all `'installs'` and sets up the date to the next record.

Note that this will work even if the places are interleaved in the data (so a code returns to a place after some period of time).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=335f3807286ef0aacaccbf62281d1b86) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Correct answer as well.

Comment: As I say in the answer, this works even if a given place is included more than once.  I think that makes it the correct answer.  The answer you selected requires that a place only appear once (you can see if you change Place3 to Place1 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go about with this. If i understood the question correct, a startdate is when the Install takes place and enddate is when a Remove takes place

```
select code
       ,place
       ,isnull(min(case when action='Install' then dt end),'1900-01-01') as startdate
       ,isnull(max(case when action='Remove'  then dt end),'3000-01-01') as enddate
  from t
group by code
        ,place
```

-------Ignore the below query, based on response from dnoeth------

```
select code
       ,place
       ,min(case when action='Install' then date else '1900-01-01' end) as startdate
       ,max(case when action='Remove'  then date else '3000-01-01' end) as enddate
  from tbl
group by code
        ,place
```

Comment: Your logic will always assign 1900-01-01 and 3000-01-01, should be `coalesce(min(case when action='Install' then date end), '1900-01-01')`

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the update, i have corrected

Comment: I didn't expect such a "simple" solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @StatsTrainer Can `Place` repeat, e.g. if this is art on loan could it be displayed at MoMA in 2022 and again in 2027? Would the `Code` be different? Otherwise the `group by` would combine the time periods in an unhelpful way.